# Parsing json values in pandas read_json

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I am reading a json file to get data. 
The json begins like this:

```
{
"rows": [
    [
        2013,
        "Mazda",
        "3",
        "917723",
        7795,
        20895
    ],
    [
        2016,
        "Cadillac",
        "ATS",
        "DD16135D",
        54890,
        66000
    ]
```

I am trying to get the values in a row into separate columns. 
I have tried doing the following:

```
df = pd.read_json(path, orient='values')
```

and got the result:

```
    rows
0  [2013, Mazda, 3, 917723, 77...
1  [2016, Cadillac, ATS, DD161...
2  [2015, Mitsubishi, Outlander,...
3  [2016, BMW, 528I, 918058, 3...
4  [2015, Toyota, Venza, 91806...
```

Ultimately, I would like to have 7 columns in my dataframe,  each column representing each item in a row. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the `json` file into a dictionary and select the `'rows'` key:

```
# replace data with open('data.json')
with data as f:
    df = pd.DataFrame(json.load(f)['rows'])

print(df)

      0         1    2         3      4      5
0  2013     Mazda    3    917723   7795  20895
1  2016  Cadillac  ATS  DD16135D  54890  66000
```

**Setup**

```
from io import StringIO
import json

data = StringIO("""{
"rows": [
    [
        2013,
        "Mazda",
        "3",
        "917723",
        7795,
        20895
    ],
    [
        2016,
        "Cadillac",
        "ATS",
        "DD16135D",
        54890,
        66000
    ]]}""")
```