# how to parse non key value json file in python

Tags: python, json

I have a json file which has data like :

```
"data": [[1467398683, "GB", "204.0.20", "tracks", "content-based", "b47911d0e80d1a8a959a2b726654bbfa", "Dance & Electronic", 1466640000, 413933, 413933,
```

I am trying to parse this non key value json file  into a dataframe in  python, can someone suggest how this can be achieved ?

Comment: Can you post the entire JSON file content?

Comment: ...because what you've posted, by itself, isn't valid JSON. Typically, the answer to "how do I parse a JSON file with Python" is "use the `json` module". If you've tried that and it didn't work, it would also help if you updated your question to show the code you've tried and explain how it failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two way:

1. Pandas read_json method have parameter (orient = 'values')

   ```
   df = pd.read_json(path, orient='values')
   ```
2. Or if you need you data like a matrix you can do this

   ```
   df = pd.DataFrame(json.load('{"data": [[1467398683,..your data...}')['data'])
   ```
3. Please see also this thread ([Parsing json values in pandas read_json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51922259/parsing-json-values-in-pandas-read-json))